# AWS architecture with limited elastic IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, elastic-ip

Right now our small-ish business has 3 clients who we have assigned to 3 elastic IPs in Amazon Web Services (AWS).

If we restart an instance no one loses access because the IPs are the same after restart.

Is there a way to handle expanding to 3 more clients without having things fall apart if there's a restart?

I'm trying to request more IPs, but they suggest it depends on our architecture, and I'm not sure what architecture they're looking for (or why some would warrant more elastic IPs than others or if this is an unchecked suggestion box).

I realize this is a very basic question, but googling around only gets me uninformative docs from the vendors mouth.

**EDIT**:

There is a lot of content on the interwebs (mostly old) about AWS supporting IPv6, but that functionality appears to be deprecated.

Comment: Architecture question #1: Why do you need an elastic IP per client?  What are they doing with the instances?  What services are in use, that the client needs to access?

Comment: why aren't you using a load balancer?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: We provide evaluation SAAS via a .NET/MVC stack allowing our users to capture event and survey data. Our clients are very interested in keeping their data separate from everyone else. That's why we've kept them separate.

Comment: @tedder42: We've looked into doing that, but our load overhead is not high enough to justify it yet. We've got a small pool of clients who have the means to keep up and running.

Answer (score 3):

You can request more EIPs in the short run. Up to 5 EIP is free depending on your account. You should also considering using name based URLs and assign each of your clients to a subdomain, for example,

```
clientA.example.com
clientB.example.com
clientC.example.com
```

This way you will not be needing an additional IP for every client you add. Depending on your traffic, one EC2 instance can serve many clients, and as you scale, you can put multiple EC2 instances behind an AWS Elastic Load Balaner, and this will scale to serve exponentially more clients.

If the client wants to keep their servers separate and can pay for them, you can purchase EIP as many as you need. You should also consider separating database into one database instance for each client, which is probably what clients desire more than separation of IPs.

For IPv6, a quick workaround would be to use a front-end ELB that supports both IPv6 and IPv4.

Comment: That might be the way we go. The downside is if clientA.example.com points to a non-elastic IP and the instance gets restarted, the clientA.example.com name is dangling off toward an IP that no longer exists. This seems like the same problem as before (someone has to go update the new IP while our users are sorry out of luck).

Comment: The benefit of using name based URLs approach is you only need to use one EIP instead of multiple IPs.

Comment: @micahhoover I updated the answer according to your edits.

Answer (score 1):

If you use elastic IPs from VPC, you get 5 per region for an AWS account. See [Amazon VPC Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_Limits.html).

So, you can go to console and select VPC. Then click on elastic IPs, create it. Once created, assign it to a relevant instance.
So, atleast for now, you can solve the problem if you are not bothered about region.